# Guess the correlation - Is there an R function in shiny to show the next plot? data collection with shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I want to show three different scatterplots with a next button. the task is to guess the strength of the correlation in each plot. the problem is that I can only see the same plot. I try to work with a next button to see the next plot.

```
library(shiny)

# 3 different dataframes/data for scatter plots
data1 <- data.frame(a <- c(20,30,35,45,50,60,80),
                    b <- c(60,70,72,77,82,88,90))
data2 <- data.frame(a <- c(20,30,35,45,50,60,80),
                    b <- c(60,70,68,77,82,88,70))
data3 <- data.frame(a <- c(35,40,38,50,52,51,30),
                    b <- c(60,70,72,64,82,88,90))

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput
    (inputId = "fit", label = "estimated correlation",
     min = 0, max = 1,     value = 0),
     actionButton("newplot", "next")),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot")))

server = function(input, output) {
output$plot <- renderPlot({
input$newplot
plot(data1)
plot(data2)
plot(data3)
  })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any built in way to do this, but you could easily keep a variable to track which plot you want to show and then use `switch()` to draw just that plot. For example

```
cycle <- function(x, max) {
  if(x() < max) {
    x(x() + 1)
  } else {
    x(1)
  }
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  index <- reactiveVal(1)
  observeEvent(input$newplot, {
    cycle(index, 3)
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    switch(index(),
      plot(data1),
      plot(data2),
      plot(data3)
    )
  })
}
```

Here I just wrote the `cycle` helper function to make it easier to loop back to 1 when increment the index. But basically it's just taking a value 1 to 3. Then in the renderPlot, it looks a the current index and only draws that plot.

Comment: thx. works. the only issue: the sliderInput start value of each new plot has now the position of the last answer/ of the previous plot. is there any way to avoid that? for example: always at zero?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your slider doesn't seem to be doing anything in your example

Comment: when I guess the correlation in the first plot, let's say I choose 50 with the slider, and click on "next" to see the second plot, then I'd see the 50 as a starting value. 
Let's say I would choose 70 for the second plot then, and click on next, i would see the 70 as the starting position. 
instead my goal is to have the starting value always on the same position for example always 0.

Comment: You can use `updateSliderInput()` to change the value of a slider. You can put that where you observe the button click.